# How to play mp3 url & document Directory mp3 file To MPMusicPlayerController

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller

Hello I am new in iOS development. I am working on music player app. I want my player to display on notification tab as well. For this I need to use `MPMusicPlayerController`, because this can't be achieved with `AVAudioPlayer`.

The problem that I am facing that all tutorials of `MPMusicPlayerController` are playing songs from music library of the iPhone, but I need to play mp3 with url or the mp3 file in document directory.

Answer (score 0):

You've more or less answered your own question. `AVAudioPlayer` can play URL based assets, but is much lower level than `MPMusicPlayerController` and it won't work with the notification page.